# How to install dynamic loaded xaps together with the main silverlight application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

I have an application that loads some xaps dynamically according to the user permissions.

Is it possible to install the shell application (OOB) and also the dynamically loaded modules so the user doesn't have to download them every time?

I would like to combine the advantage of the thin shell (fast initial loading time) with the out of browser one (no download until the next version).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no "out of the box" way to do this. What you could try is have it so the first time the OOB app is launched, download the external xaps and store them locally in isolated storage. Then in the future the OOB app can load the xaps from there instead of re-downloading them.